# ASP.NET MaskedEditExtender needs to show mm/dd/yyyy when user clicks on textbox

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskedtextbox, maskededitextender

I am using the MaskedEditExtender control for a textbox field that contains Date of Birth.  I want the mask to show "mm/dd/yyyy" when the user clicks on the textbox when it is empty.  Right now it only shows "***_*_**/_/__"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [you can set](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) the `PromptCharacter` to something else, but I don't think you can specify multiple prompt characters in one textbox.  Because of this I would say your options are limited to:

- Javascript schenanigans where you replace the "_" with m,d or y depending on where it is in the text box.
- Multiple textboxes